# Why is a message in WCF seemingly always in SOAP format?

Tags: wcf, serialization, soap, basichttpbinding, wcf-serialization

I have implemented a message inspector in WCF by implementing `IDispatchMessageInspector`.

Putting a break point on this method...

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
    // Impementation
}
```

... I can look at the `request` object to see what is inside.

Clearly I dont understand WCF enough because whatever endpoint binding I use (basichttp, nettcp and netpipe) the message inside is always represented in SOAP format e.g.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
    <s:Header>
        -- headers --
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        -- body --
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Is this because doing a .ToString() on the request object just represents the message in SOAP format?

I imagined that using another protocol e.g. netTcp would result in a different message payload.

Also lets say I wanted to represent my data in JSON format how would I go about doing this? Or would I end up with JSON formatted data structures inside a SOAP envelope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because all bindings you mentioned are designed to use SOAP protocol. They are using either `TextMessageEncoder` or `BinaryMessageEncoder` and both these work with SOAP envelopes (except the situation where you use `TextMessageEncoder` in custom binding with `MessageVersion` set to `None`).

The only out-of-the box binding allowing other message formats is `WebHttpBinding` which uses `WebMessageEncoder` supporting both XML and JSON.