# In which format messages are sent in WCF

Tags: wcf

**Context**

I am new to `WCF`.

I was reading an article about message contract and found that `WCF` is sending message using `SOAP`.

My doubt is, if we are enabled `REST in WCF service`, then will it still use `SOAP` format for exchanging data.

In `WebGet` and `WebInvoke` attribute[which are for `REST`], we are mentioning the inputformat like `JSON` or `XML`.

**Question**

If messages are sent through `SOAP`, then why are those needed ?

If all message contracts are sent using SOAP format, then message contract should not work in case of webHttp binding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is a message in WCF seemingly always in SOAP format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024367/why-is-a-message-in-wcf-seemingly-always-in-soap-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The protocol format will depend on the binding you select. Here's [`a list of the different system provided bindings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879(v=vs.110).aspx) and the underlying protocol they use.

> In WebGet and WebInvoke attribute[which are for REST], we are
>   mentioning the inputformat like JSON or XML.
>   If messages are sent through SOAP, then why are those needed.

If you use the `WebHttpBinding` which uses standard HTTP instead of SOAP then those attributes allow you to specify whether you want to format the requests using plain XML (not SOAP) or JSON.

Comment: Will MessageContract work in case of webHttp ? I read that MessageContract works on SOAP protocol.

Comment: No, message contracts are SOAP specific. You need to use Data Contracts with webHttp. By the way if you want to expose a RESTful API, wouldn't ASP.NET Web API be a more suitable solution than WCF for you?

Comment: Thanks a ton Darin..I got the answer.